# Process Google Sheet cell with javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a value in one of my cells that I would like to access, parse, and output a derive value in another cell. To do what I want in google sheet functions would be very tedious.

Is there to write and call an App script function in the cell? I'm new to App Scripts, but I thought this might be possible.

Answer (score 1):

yes.  you're talking about writing a "custom function"

so you'd write a function in the script editor like this:

```
myCustomFunction(value){
   [your appscript code]
   return newValue
}
```

Then you place this in a cell:

```
=myCustomFunction(B2)
```

or some other reference to a cell, and it should return the result of your appscript manipulations.

Comment: Where is the script editor?

Comment: Extensions>AppScript @pixelearth

Comment: Hm, it wasn't loading at first, but it seems like now it is. I didn't need to deploy.

Comment: MattKing is there a way to store the Apps Script with the sheet, or do they just live in different places? Strange.

Comment: check out some of these resources on AppScript:
https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/
https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/
https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: @pixelearth it is stored with the sheet.  it's just accesed in a different browser tab.